# using get line in c++

Tags: c++, string, getline

Okay, I am trying to use the code:

```
getline(cin, phrase);
```

When I compile I get the error:
no matching function for call to 'getline'

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Challenge 1\n" << "Kaitlin Stevers\n" << "Characters and Strings" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    char letter[2];
    cout << "Please enter a letter: " << endl;
    cin >> letter;
    cout << "You entered: " << letter << endl;

    char word[5];
    cout << "Please enter a word up to 5 characters long: " << endl;
    cin >> word;
    cout << "The word you entered is: " << word << endl;

    char phrase[100];
    cout << "Please enter a phrase up to 99 characters long: " << endl;
    getline(cin, phrase);
    cout << "The phrase you entered is: " << phrase << endl;

    string lettero;
    cout << "Enter one letter: " << endl;
    cin >> lettero; 
    cout << "The letter you entered is: " << lettero << endl;

    string wordo;
    cout << "Please enter a word: " << endl;
    cin >> wordo;
    cout << "The word you entered is: " << wordo << endl;

    string phraseo;
    cout << "Please enter five words: " << endl;
    getline(cin, phraseo);
    cout << "The words you entered are: " << phraseo << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the answer is in the documentation of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'no matching function call for getline',  cause [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) takes a string not a char[] as argument. See [cin.getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) if you absolutely want to pass a cha[] as argument.

Answer (score 1):

As you see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

This `getline(cin, string)` function accepts a **string**.

Although, there is also an instruction you can use to put the line into a char array [like so](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

```
char phrase[99];
cin.getline (phrase,99);
```

Or you could also get the input into a string, then convert it to a char array :

```
 string temp = "";
 cin >> temp;
 char phrase[99];
 strcpy(phrase, temp.c_str());
```